# Rename and create a dataframe inside a For loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

i have a list `['jan','feb']` and i am trying to loop in a for loop for creating a dataframe

```
    name = ['jan','feb']
    for month in name:
       df = pd.DataFrame(name, columns = ['month'])
```

This is the current output i'm getting.

df

```
           month
        0    jan
        1    feb
```

What i required is to creating a df w.r.t to the values in list.
So when 1st value in list is passed `'jan'`.

Is there a way to rename  and creating the df while looping?

jan

```
           month
        0    jan
```

feb

```
           month
        0    feb
```

Comment: Try adding a continue statement after the df variable. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you are giving, you are recreating the same dataframe over and over again. You would achieve the same with a simple

```
   df = pd.DataFrame(name, columns = ['month'])
```

You are not using the loop variable `month` in the loop.

I believe you want to create multiple dataframes, one for each month. To do this, you could use a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {}

name = ['jan','feb']
for month in name:
    df_dict[month] = pd.DataFrame([month])

for month in name:
    print("key: ", month)    
    print("dataframe:")
    print(df_dict[month], end='\n\n')
```

resulting in

```
key:  jan
dataframe:
     0
0  jan

key:  feb
dataframe:
     0
0  feb
```

In order to create variables (though I am not sure why you would want to do this), you can modify the above code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

name = ['jan','feb']
for month in name:
    globals()[month] = pd.DataFrame([month])

print(jan)
print(feb)
```

Comment: how do i get seperate dfs, like jan or feb

Comment: Just modified the answer to create variables for each entry of `name`.